# convert display to monochrome

Tags: debian, x11, display-settings, color-management

My Asus netbook has Debian Wheezy. I came across a weird idea. How would it look if my display screen is monochrome. Is it possible to configure X11 to make the display monochrome?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the bit depth to 1. For `Xorg`, you want to fiddle with:

```
Section "Screen"
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth "x"
```

in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Reading the `xorg.conf(5)` man page you'll discover:

> `Depth`  *depth*
>
> This entry specifies what colour depth the Display  subsection  is  to  be used  for. ... The range of depth values that are allowed depends on the driver.  Most drivers support 8, 15, 16 and 24. Some also  support 1  and/or  4,  and  some  may support other values (like 30).

I would suggest trying with a nested X11 server like Xephyr or with Xvnc first, although you might hit the same problem there (i.e. the server not supporting it).

In addition, you are very likely to experience all sorts of strange behaviour in applications - starting from weird pixmap artefacts to crashes in code which silently expects [True color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Color) depth.